# SQL query on arrow duckdb workflow in R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, apache-arrow, duckdb

I'm wondering if it is possible to send an SQL query on `duckdb` during `arrow` workflow in R. (https://duckdb.org/2021/12/03/duck-arrow.html)

I know it is intended to use `dplyr` verbs, but there are some verbs that are not smoothly translated that codes that works on `dplyr` backend but not on either `duckdb` or `arrow`.

I would like to use a direct `SQL` query during the call, something like below example:

```r
library(duckdb)
library(arrow)
library(dplyr)

# Open dataset using year,month folder partition
ds <- arrow::open_dataset("nyc-taxi", partitioning = c("year", "month"))

ds %>%
  # Pass off to DuckDB
  to_duckdb() |>
  SQL_QUERY("SELECT * LIMIT 100") |> # <- something like this
  collect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to accomplish, you can use SQL query fragments with the `dplyr` verbs:

```
ds |>
  to_duckdb() |>
  filter(sql("vendor_name = 'VTS' AND year = 2009 AND month = 1")) |>
  collect()
```

You can find more information about this approach in one of the [dbplyr vignettes](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/sql.html).

This approach doesn't extend to more complex queries. However, you can use the information returned by `to_duckdb()` to send full SQL queries with the DBI package:

```
db_tbl <-  ds |>
      to_duckdb(table_name = "nyc_tbl")

con <- db_tbl$src$con
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM 'nyc_tbl' LIMIT 100")
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be like this since you're doing it `dplyr` style and skipping over the `SQL` style

```
ds %>%
    to_duckdb() %>%
    head(100) %>%
    collect()
```